# Getting a "The Table already exists" error when running an append query in Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, append

I'm getting a strange error in my access database.

The Error:

> The table '[insert table name here]' already exists.  You created or
>   renamed a table and then tried to save it.  before Microsoft access
>   could save the table, another user created or renamed one using the
>   same name.

This is happening when an RPA team runs an Access Macro that is just a list of queries to run in sequence.

The error comes up during an append query that takes records from one table and adds them to another table that is the core of a work environment.

This is only happening to the RPA team.  When I run the same Macro from my workstation, it runs flawlessly.  When 2 other people who are authorized run the Macro, it runs flawlessly.  I can't duplicate it.  I also cannot find any reference to this error in this circumstance in the time I have spent on google or here.  I'm stumped.  I could just be typing in keyword searches wrong, but I don't quite know where to go next with this.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:  Here is the SQL for the offending Append query.  It's ugly, but it's what I have to work with :)

```
INSERT INTO [New ZSPWAR Prime] (Payer, AI, Bill_doc, 
            Sqwak, Site, Plnt, Billing_Dt, ProfitCntr, Customer, 
            Equipment, Issued_Material, Material_Description, SLoc, 
            Serial_No, ItCC, Mtrl_Grp, Manuf_No, Manuf_Name, RTN, 
            Warranty, PPC, SVO_No, Ref_No, Notification_Subject, 
            AC_C, Corrective_Action, SB_Data, AC_R, Corr_Action_R, 
            SaleDebCre, Sales_Ord, SO_Date, SU, Returned_Material, 
            Returned_SNR, [Reason for Rejection], SLCo, Canel_Doc, 
            Can_Doc_Dt, Tail, ItCa, Sold_to, Sold_to_Name, 
            Customer_PO_No, [User], Comp_Date, OB_Del_NO, OB_Del_DT,
            Ret_Delv, Rt_SO_It, Ret_Date, Ret_EQUI, Ret_Note, 
            NoteCR_DT, NoteCM_DT, Ret_Note_DESC, WACD, 
            Wty_Prog_Code_Desc, PO_NO, PO_DT, PO_PI, VR_Amount, 
            INV_PT_DT, ZZ07, Freight_Amt, [ME23N PO_Owner], VDCD, 
            Ven_Den_Code_Desc, DISP, [Disp code Descr], PRI, HVNE, 
            [Approve By], [MM Vendor Number], [Sourcing Vendor Number],
            [Sourcing Vendor Name], [Vendor Contract], [FFF Class],
            [Ref Contract], [Company Code], [BUSAC TYPE], 
            [Warr Typ], [Aircraft Material], [Aircraft Serial Number],
            [Aircraft Program], [GL Date], [Obj Type], [ID Number],
            [MD04 Purchasing Group], [MD04 PurG Name], [RO Number], 
            [RO Creation Date], [RO Contact Name], [RO Vendor Code], 
            [RO Vendor Name], [ODC Amount], [Issue_New/Rotable], 
            Issue_Core, [Recovery_New/Rotable], Recovery_Core, 
            Labor_Hours, Rate, Labor_Cost, Mtrl_Qty_Billed, 
            Mtrl_ea_Cost, Mtrl_ttl_Cost, Total_Cost, MAUC_STD, 
            Core_cost, Cat_Price, Discount, [% Discount], 
            [ODC Freight], [Repair Cost], [Material Burden], 
            [% Material Burden], [Rotable Depreciation], [% Core Dep],
            [Net Spend], Margin, Item_Cost, [Total Material Burden],
            [Total Rotables Dep], SVO_Direct_Labor, SVO_Labor_OH) 
SELECT [New ZSPWAR Merge].Payer, [New ZSPWAR Merge].AI, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Bill_doc, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Sqwak, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Site, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Plnt, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Billing_Dt, [New ZSPWAR Merge].ProfitCntr,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Customer, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Equipment,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Issued_Material, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Material_Description,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SLoc, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Serial_No, [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCC,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Mtrl_Grp, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Manuf_No, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Manuf_Name,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].RTN, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Warranty, [New ZSPWAR Merge].PPC,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SVO_No, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ref_No, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Notification_Subject,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].AC_C, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Corrective_Action,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SB_Data, [New ZSPWAR Merge].AC_R, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Corr_Action_R, [New ZSPWAR Merge].SaleDebCre,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Sales_Ord, [New ZSPWAR Merge].SO_Date,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SU, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Returned_Material,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Returned_SNR, [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Reason for Rejection],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SLCo, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Canel_Doc, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Can_Doc_Dt, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Tail, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCa, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Sold_to, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Sold_to_Name, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Customer_PO_No,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].User, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Comp_Date, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].OB_Del_NO, [New ZSPWAR Merge].OB_Del_DT,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ret_Delv, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Rt_SO_It,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ret_Date, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ret_EQUI,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ret_Note, [New ZSPWAR Merge].NoteCR_DT,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].NoteCM_DT, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ret_Note_DESC,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].WACD, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Wty_Prog_Code_Desc,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].PO_NO, [New ZSPWAR Merge].PO_DT, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].PO_PI, [New ZSPWAR Merge].VR_Amount, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].INV_PT_DT, [New ZSPWAR Merge].ZZ07, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Freight_Amt, [New ZSPWAR Merge].[ME23N PO_Owner],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].VDCD, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Ven_Den_Code_Desc,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].DISP, [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Disp code Descr],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].PRI, [New ZSPWAR Merge].HVNE, [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Approve By],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[MM Vendor Number], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Sourcing Vendor Number], 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Sourcing Vendor Name], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Vendor Contract], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[FFF Class],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Ref Contract], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Company Code],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[BUSAC TYPE], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Warr Typ],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Aircraft Material], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Aircraft Serial Number], 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Aircraft Program], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[GL Date],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Obj Type], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[ID Number],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[MD04 Purchasing Group], 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[MD04 PurG Name], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[RO Number],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[RO Creation Date], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[RO Contact Name], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[RO Vendor Code], 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[RO Vendor Name], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[ODC Amount],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Issue_New/Rotable], [New ZSPWAR Merge].Issue_Core,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Recovery_New/Rotable], [New ZSPWAR Merge].Recovery_Core,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Labor_Hours, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Rate, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Labor_Cost, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Mtrl_Qty_Billed, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Mtrl_ea_Cost,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Mtrl_ttl_Cost, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Total_Cost,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].MAUC_STD, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Core_cost,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Cat_Price, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Discount,
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[% Discount], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[ODC Freight],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Repair Cost], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Material Burden],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[% Material Burden], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Rotable Depreciation], 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[% Core Dep], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Net Spend],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].Margin, [New ZSPWAR Merge].Item_Cost, 
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Total Material Burden], [New ZSPWAR Merge].[Total Rotables Dep],
       [New ZSPWAR Merge].SVO_Direct_Labor, [New ZSPWAR Merge].SVO_Labor_OH
FROM   [New ZSPWAR Merge]
WHERE  ( ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].Bill_doc ) NOT LIKE "1*" )
         AND ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCC ) LIKE "ZCOM" )
         AND ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCa ) NOT LIKE "ZRN*" )
       )
        OR ( ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].Bill_doc ) NOT LIKE "1*"
             )
             AND ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCC ) LIKE "ZCOM" )
             AND ( ( [New ZSPWAR Merge].ItCa ) NOT LIKE "I*"
                 ) );
```

Apologies, the code snippet feature doesn't seem to like me today.

Comment: please show your code,  (**Which line** of the macro generates the error?)

Comment: @ashleedawg Added the code to the post.  doesn't look quite right though.  Not good with the formatting here.

Comment: No worries, I fixed that

Comment: I'm puzzled by the error message text.  Does your database actually include a table named `[insert table name here]`?

Comment: What is the RPA team? Is there something special about this team that might help us figure this problem out? (Like, maybe they all use mobile computers instead of desktops, they all use  Mac instead of Windows, they're all remote users instead of on-site, they all belong to a different company, etc...)

Comment: I would check the settings of any report. Often a report (or form) is set to lock the whole table. If a report is open, and you run the append query, it will fail. So check the reports setting property  sheet (other tab). Make sure the report is not set to lock the  whole table - it will prevent  inserts and updates from other users.

Comment: Any vba executed before executing this query?

Comment: @HansUp, The actual Table name is something else.  the error message is actually giving the Query name as a Table name, which is a huge part of the question

Comment: @StoneGiant The RPA team are contractors in India.  Our company is primarily in the US and Canada.  The RPA team is using a virtual machine via Citrix to access SAP and our shared drive.  AFAIK they are using desktops.  Lag has been an issue too.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal the problem query is in a Macro that runs a series of queries.  The very first thing the macro does is export a table to excel so I have a kind of running backup.  That completes before any other steps.  This query is the next step.

Comment: When you say _the error message is actually giving the Query name_, are you saying the error message is naming the append query in your OP? So, if the above query is named **qryDoAppend**, you get the message _The table 'qryDoAppend' already exists_?  I ask, because this is looking a lot like a multi-user problem, especially in the face of lag. If multiple RPA team members are running the macro at the same time, they may be trying to create a temporary table with the same name during the execution cycle. But if the query is being named in the error, that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @StoneGiant In this example, the error message gives the name of the query, not of any existing tables.  As far as I know there is only tw RPA team members working on it and they use a single virtual machine to run it, once at a time.  I don't know if the RPA software they are using is trying to trigger the Macro twice instead of just once.  I have theories, but they are almost based entirely of guesses and bullhockey

Comment: Like I noted, the insert into that table can fail say if a report remains open based on that table you are inserting to. if no chance of a report being open that using that output table (the append into table), then my suggest likely don't apply - but is something to check and be aware of (that a open report on that table could cause the table to be locked, and thus your appending query will fail - but not all the time.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal That's just the thing.  This is happening when anyone who uses the DB is not in the office.  The RPA team is working on the back end and they only have one instance of the DB open at a time.

Comment: @PaulTIKI mentioned that the RPA users are using the DB in Citrix. I bet there are 2 remote users running the SAME copy of the DB on the Citrix server and running the macro at the same time, causing this issue. You have not given enough background info. Is this a split database? Do most users have the front end on their PC and the back end on the server? But, maybe the Citrix users all run the same front end? Please provide more environment and setup details. If 2 users in a remote desktop server run the same DB file (i.e. C:\DB\MyDB.accdb) at the same time in two sessions, problems can arise.

Answer (score 1):

IF this is an RPA Solution can I assume you  have created a workflow where a table is created and then data is inserted into it?

IF so there might be a step missing  when you delete the table after it is used.
OR you need to check if the table exists before trying to create it.

You can Try this

```
Public Function ifTableExists(tblName As String) As Boolean

    If DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = '" & tblName & "'") = 1 Then

        ifTableExists = True

    End If

End Function
```